# Sign a callback URL

Tags: hash, digital-signature

I have a Single Sign-On system that works this way :

User clicks link on `clientsite.com` that redirect him to

```
mastersite.com?returnTo=http://clientsite.com
```

If auth is valid, the user is redirected to :

```
http://clientsite.com?token=xxxx
```

As I don't want `http://clientsite.com` to be among a list of authorised websites I decided to do the following :

All the clientsite share a common secret random key such as

```
client_token = "VDFdzbZ3qFvWyx5dUMdEDmwnS7T"
```

and do the following :

```
time = time();    
hash = hash_sha256(client_token + time + http://clientsite.com)
redirecto to : mastersite.com?returnTo=http://clientsite.com&time=time&key=hash
```

the master site then check :

```
is time < time() - 10min ?
is hash_sha256(client_token + time + http://clientsite.com) == hash ?
```

Is this schema secure enough ?

The only problem I see is if I decide to change the client_key I need to update many websites, can I overcome this ?

Comment: What do you mean that you would have to change many sites? Are there many sites with the same key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> hash_sha256(client_token + time + http://clientsite.com) == hash

This looks like it will be vulnerable to [length-extension attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack). You probably want to use [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) instead of plain hashing with sha256; or use a hashing function that is not vulnerable to length extension attack.

Answer (score 2):

Also, there are a few protocols that do essentially exactly what you are doing here, CAS is the one that comes to mind for me, and how I solved this particular need. It's built specifically for this use case. the reference implementation of CAS is built in Java, which is sort of annoying, but there are other implementations out there, and writing your own isn't that difficult. The bonus of using a protocol like CAS is you mostly get to push off "is the protocol secure" to the designers of the protocol.

Comment: Actually I faced this problem while implementing CAS! I didn't saw info about how am I supposed to sign my callback URL in the documentation I rode